# How to fix eslint errors when using React context (consumer-provider)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm using [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) with ESLint enabled and having some issues fixing ESLint issues.

**Provider:**

```
 return (
      <AuthorizationContext.Provider
        value={{ isAuthorized: this.state.isAuthorized }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthorizationContext.Provider>
```

**Problem:**
ESLint reports `Parsing error: Unexpected token .` for `<AuthorizationContext.Provider>`

**Consumer:**

```
 <AuthorizationConsumer>
        {({ isAuthorized}) => {
          return (
             // some code here
          )
        }}
      </AuthorizationConsumer>
```

**Problem:**
ESLint reports `Parsing error: Unexpected token {` for `{({ isAuthorized}) => {`

[ESLint configuration](https://gist.github.com/nevinvalsaraj/f3aad026dceade6541b6b2a052b8e27d).

Comment: Your file is a `.jsx`?

Comment: I would suggest also to compare your config with the create-react-app one https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/.eslintrc.json

Comment: `<AuthorizationContext.Consumer>`

Comment: @soywod It's a `.js` file but I have configured `"jsx": true` in eslintrc.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi I have exported `const AuthorizationConsumer = AuthorizationContext.Consumer`.

Comment: Could you share your full components?

Answer (score -1):

With your configuration, I have no error: https://codesandbox.io/s/j2km74l0y9

But I get the same error when `<AuthorizationContext.Provider>` is not inside a function, or when the code is not valid. Maybe check your component.